# Postgres - Time comparison query with user's local time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When i run below command in my rails console, i get the current local time .

```
> Time.current.getlocal
 => 2018-03-20 17:48:38 +0530
```

But when i use this in query, the result is different , please check below query

```
warehouse = Warehouse.joins(:timings).where("timings.day = ? and timings.open_at < ? and timings.close_at > ?", Date.current.strftime("%A"), Time.current.getlocal, Time.current.getlocal).group("warehouses.id")


Warehouse Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "warehouses".* FROM "warehouses" INNER JOIN "timings" ON "timings"."warehouse_id" = "warehouses"."id" WHERE (timings.day = 'Tuesday' and timings.open_at < '2018-03-20 12:18:44.783130' and timings.close_at > '2018-03-20 12:18:44.783166') GROUP BY warehouses.id LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

I want to know why postgres query not taking local time ?

Comment: `select pg_typeof(open_at) from timings;` is `timestamp without time zone` ?..

Comment: Sorry.i dont understand what you want to say ? i dont have brief knowledge in postgres. data type of `open_at` field is `TIME`

Comment: so data type `type` has no knowledge of time zones, this is why `2018-03-20 17:48:38 +0530` is translated to `2018-03-20 12:18:44.783130`

Comment: So what is the solution for that ?

Comment: solution for what?.. it translates time correctly. tell the expected result

Comment: can i use `Pacific Time (US & Canada) `timezone in above query, `  i tried this query  `Warehouse.joins(:timings).where("timings.day = ? and timings.open_at::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '#{Time.zone.now.formatted_offset}' < ? and timings.close_at::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '#{Time.zone.now.formatted_offset}' > ? ", Date.current.strftime("%A"), Time.current, Time.current).group("warehouses.id")` but no success
`